# Issue about configuration on express-session middleware used in Express 4.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

i am new in node.js.  i still couldn't figure out the meaning of configuration on session. 
below is example of basic use of session

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser('cookie'));
app.use(session({
    cookie: {
        domain: 'localhost',
        signed: false,
        maxAge:100000,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    secret:'cookie',
    rolling:false,
    unset:'keep'
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('this is a router base page!');
});

app.get('/index1.html', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index1.html');
    next();
});

app.get('/index1.html', function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.session.id);
});

app.post('/index1.html', function (req, res) {
   if(!req.session.user) req.session.user = req.body;
   res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
   res.write('session:' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
   res.write('expires:'+ JSON.stringify(req.session.cookie.maxAge/1000));
   res.end();
});
app.listen(1338);
```

when i refresh `localhost:1338/index.html`many times, the `req.session.id` changes accordingly such as

```
CboUX1OOMa1veStAmf_9fsEd-ZwNYlW  
kWkgsLXsDJcbtEIt9gfSWbg4_ScbG44p 
jXLUt0fcCa-wH_jYsU64GznGj1ZNR44G 
FjmjRHahDlaC79ngg7k2n1yWni6OHqpt
eLauXn3_SFNxmcWbHMZKAL4d0OVTwzqC
```

i don't get it why it changes every time even i haven't use post method.

if it changes according to every refreshing web page, what is the difference from `req.session.regenerate`

```
req.session.regenerate(function(err){
     console.log(req.session.id);
  });
```

but after i wrote username and password in front end form,and submit, then refresh web page again, it won't print session.id any more.

I think i may have some misunderstanding on concept of session. 
can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

It should give you same token if you introduce time duration setting in session configuration. Something like this

```
activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000
```

If you are interested for more detail please visit this link https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions

Comment: sorry, after i add `activeDuration` . i don't see much difference, and there is no such property in this middleware docs.  but i kind of figure out. once session config is set, and i refresh web page but don't assign value, server   will response different session.id every time but no value. but once i set value to session, the session.id won't change anymore.  however, if i regenerate session.id, the id will be changed every time web page refresh. the uninitiated session means session.id is generated by no value set, am I right?